# How to prove that $\,\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+i}}\,$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following question :

> Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+i}}$$ diverges, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

I am not sure how to progress with it. Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: What is $i$? ${}{}{}{}$ (Sounds bad.)

Comment: according to MMA, it does not converge.

Comment: I guess [my previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533014/divergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-cos-lognn/533054#533054) would be helpful.

Comment: @learner Mathematica.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/532396/5531), though I hesitate to mark it as a duplicate in light of sos440's nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is essentially the same question as [Divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\log(n))}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533014/103402) and [Divergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{i+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532396/103402), maybe one more explanation will help. The argument of $n^i = \exp(i\log n)$ changes slowly when $n$ is large. More precisely, within the range $\{n: k\le n\le 2k \}$ the argument changes by at most $\log 2\le \pi/4$. When $|\arg z|\le \pi/4$, we have $\operatorname{Re}z\ge |z|/\sqrt{2}$. 
Hence, 
$$
\operatorname{Re}  e^{i\log k}\sum_{n=k}^{2k} \frac{1}{n^{1+i} } = 
\operatorname{Re}  \sum_{n=k}^{2k} \frac{e^{i (\log k -\log n)}}{n  } \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=k}^{2k} \frac{1}{n  } \ge \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} $$ where the last inequality uses the fact that each of $2k+1$ terms is at least $1/2k$. Thus, the series fails the Cauchy criterion for convergence.